# How can I fix this framework so the services can be defined in any order?

Tags: javascript

As to the effectiveness of this simple framework design, maybe you think it's terrible, but I'm really just interested in making it work and learn the hard way why certain designs are good or bad. I want to make it work even it's its a bad design.

So I'm facing a challenge with this: If the code that defines a service depending on another service is executed *before* that service which it depends on, it will think the component doesn't exist. Because that code hasn't executed yet. My goal is to be able to execute the code defining the services in any order.

Hopefully that makes some sense. The issue is a bit hard for me to explain, but my goal is to write the code like this:

```
new Service('machine', ['machine / components / gear'], function(gear) {
  alert('This machine depends on a ' + gear);
}).initialize();

new Service('machine / components / gear', ['machine / components / gear / components / cog'], function(cog) {
  return 'gear wich depends on a ' + cog;
});

new Service('machine / components / gear / components / cog', [], function(cog) {
  return 'cog';
});
```

For the sake of this question, the first argument supplied to the Service constructor is the name of the service. The way I originally wrote the framework, `'machine'` in this case is executed before `'machine / components / gear'` so it can't see that `'machine / components / gear'` exists, and, similarly, `'machine / components / gear'` is executed before `'machine / components / gear / components / cog'` so it fails to use that component.

Note, before showing the code: You'll see a `count` variable used within the framework, and some weird things, basically it was all very simple and neat until I started attempting to mitigate this problem I'm having. As you'll see, I've tried to solve the problem by, when finding a dependency doesn't exist, using `setTimeout` and trying again until `count` has been increased a few times, therefore the event loop has completed a few times and perhaps the other services have finished executing. This is messy, probably a terrible way to do it.

Here's the code:

```
var Directory = function() {
  this.directories = {};
  this.items = {};
};
var root = new Directory();
var Service = function(name, dependencies, func, count) {
  if (!count) {
    count = 0;
  }
  var that = this;
  this.name = name;
  this.wait = false;
  this.dependencyCollection = [];
  this.func = func;
  this.initialize = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Initializing with dependency collection: '); //debugging
      console.log(that.dependencyCollection); //debugging
      that.func.apply(null, that.dependencyCollection);
    }, 10);
  };
  this.eventHandlers = {};
  this.trigger = function(name) {
    if (that.eventHandlers[name]) {
      that.eventHandlers[name]();
    }
  };
  this.on = function(name, func) {
    that.eventHandlers[name] = func;
  };
  this.mutate = function(dependencies, func) {
    new Service(that.name, dependencies, func);
    that.trigger('mutate');
  };
  for (var x = 0; x < dependencies.length; x++) {
    var nameSegments = dependencies[x].split(' / ');
    var service = root;
    var servicePlaceholder = service;
    for (var i = 0; i < nameSegments.length; i++) {
      var segment = nameSegments[i];
      if (i === nameSegments.length - 1) {
        if (servicePlaceholder.items[segment]) {
          console.log('Observing dependency: ' + servicePlaceholder.items[segment]());
          this.dependencyCollection.push(servicePlaceholder.items[segment]());
        } else {
          if (count < 3) {
            (function(count) {
              setTimeout(function() {
                count++;
                new Service(name, dependencies, func, count);
              }, 1)
            })(count);
          } else {
            throw 'Dependent item missing: ' + JSON.stringify(servicePlaceholder.items, null, 3) + ' (' + dependencies + ": " + segment + ')';
          }
        }
      } else if (servicePlaceholder.directories[segment]) {
        servicePlaceholder = servicePlaceholder.directories[segment];
      } else {
        if (count < 3) {
          (function(count) {
            setTimeout(function() {
              count++;
              new Service(name, dependencies, func, count);
            }, 1)
          })(count);
        } else {
          throw 'Dependent directory missing: ' + JSON.stringify(servicePlaceholder.directories, null, 3) + ' (' + segment + ')';
        }
      }
    }
  }
  var directory = root;
  var directoryPlaceholder = directory;
  var nameSegments = name.split(' / ');
  for (var i = 0; i < nameSegments.length; i++) {
    var segment = nameSegments[i];
    if (i === nameSegments.length - 1) {
      console.log('Observing dependency collection: ' + that.dependencyCollection);
      directoryPlaceholder.items[segment] = function() {
        return that.func.apply(null, that.dependencyCollection);
      }
    } else {
      if (directoryPlaceholder.directories[segment]) {
        directoryPlaceholder = directoryPlaceholder.directories[segment];
      } else {
        directoryPlaceholder.directories[segment] = new Directory();
        directoryPlaceholder = directoryPlaceholder.directories[segment];
      }
    }
  }
};
```

If anything in there doesn't make sense, just assume it was a futile attempt to mitigate the problem. I've been working with it for many hours and finally decided I was getting nowhere and to ask for help. I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me figure out how to make this (perhaps terrible) model execute properly.

Example of the code without the timeouts and counter and whatnot, working properly except only if you define the components in chronological order:

```js
var Directory = function() {
  this.directories = {};
  this.items = {};
};
var root = new Directory();
var Service = function(name, dependencies, func) {
  var that = this;
  this.name = name;
  this.wait = false;
  this.dependencyCollection = [];
  this.func = func;
  this.initialize = function() {
    that.func.apply(null, that.dependencyCollection);
  };
  this.eventHandlers = {};
  this.trigger = function(name) {
    if (that.eventHandlers[name]) {
      that.eventHandlers[name]();
    }
  };
  this.on = function(name, func) {
    that.eventHandlers[name] = func;
  };
  this.mutate = function(dependencies, func) {
    new Service(that.name, dependencies, func);
    that.trigger('mutate');
  };
  for (var x = 0; x < dependencies.length; x++) {
    var nameSegments = dependencies[x].split(' / ');
    var service = root;
    var servicePlaceholder = service;
    for (var i = 0; i < nameSegments.length; i++) {
      var segment = nameSegments[i];
      if (i === nameSegments.length - 1) {
        if (servicePlaceholder.items[segment]) {
          console.log('Observing dependency: ' + servicePlaceholder.items[segment]());
          this.dependencyCollection.push(servicePlaceholder.items[segment]());
        } else {
          throw 'Dependent item missing: ' + JSON.stringify(servicePlaceholder.items, null, 3) + ' (' + dependencies + ": " + segment + ')';
        }
      } else if (servicePlaceholder.directories[segment]) {
        servicePlaceholder = servicePlaceholder.directories[segment];
      } else {
        throw 'Dependent directory missing: ' + JSON.stringify(servicePlaceholder.directories, null, 3) + ' (' + segment + ')';
      }
    }
  }
  var directory = root;
  var directoryPlaceholder = directory;
  var nameSegments = name.split(' / ');
  for (var i = 0; i < nameSegments.length; i++) {
    var segment = nameSegments[i];
    if (i === nameSegments.length - 1) {
      console.log('Observing dependency collection: ' + that.dependencyCollection);
      directoryPlaceholder.items[segment] = function() {
        return that.func.apply(null, that.dependencyCollection);
      }
    } else {
      if (directoryPlaceholder.directories[segment]) {
        directoryPlaceholder = directoryPlaceholder.directories[segment];
      } else {
        directoryPlaceholder.directories[segment] = new Directory();
        directoryPlaceholder = directoryPlaceholder.directories[segment];
      }
    }
  }
};

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(root);
}, 1000);

new Service('machine / components / gear / components / cog', [], function(cog) {
  return 'cog';
});

new Service('machine / components / gear', ['machine / components / gear / components / cog'], function(cog) {
  return 'gear wich depends on a ' + cog;
});

new Service('machine', ['machine / components / gear'], function(gear) {
  alert('This machine depends on a ' + gear);
}).initialize();
```

Comment: What if you placed any services with dependencies that haven't been registered yet into some kind of queue. Then, whenever you register another component you check if any of the services in the queue can now run?

Comment: [Here's a simplified example](https://jsfiddle.net/e0j0eLLv/) of what I'm talking about.

Comment: @MikeC I don't want the missing dependencies to fail silently though. When would your approach throw an error? I don't know of a way in JS to know when the script is finished executing, so I can check "Anything left in the queue? Yeah? Alright, throw an error." Maybe `setTimeout` would do that?

Comment: You'd have to determine the end point yourself. If you don't allow the user to dynamically add scripts as they go, just do a `setTimeout` and see if the queue is empty or not. By the time the `setTimeout` callback runs, all of the other scripts will have been loaded and run. [Updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/e0j0eLLv/2/)

Comment: Alright this looks good. I'll expose a function to the user to throw errors for remaining items in the queue on the user's own terms. Make this an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to handle this is to add services with missing dependencies to a queue. Every time a new component is registered, see if the items in the queue have the dependencies they need.

Finally, to catch the case where dependencies are *not* resolved, use `setTimeout` to check the queue after all of the scripts have loaded and report back on any components which never had their dependencies resolved.

```js
var Service = (function() {
 var _registered = {};
  var _waiting = [];
  
  // Check if all dependencies have been resolved
  setTimeout(function() {
   _waiting.forEach(function(obj) {
     throw new Error('Failed to resolve dependencies for ' + obj.name);
    });
  }, 1);
  
  function allDependenciesLoaded(dependencies) {
   return dependencies.every(function(dep) {
     return !!_registered[dep];
    });
  }
  
  function processWaiting() {
   for (var i = _waiting.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     var obj = _waiting[i];
      if (allDependenciesLoaded(obj.dependencies)) {
       _waiting.splice(i, 1);
        obj.func();
      }
    }
  }
  
  return function(componentName, dependencies, func) {
   _registered[componentName] = func;
    if (!allDependenciesLoaded(dependencies)) {
     _waiting.push({
       name: componentName,
        dependencies: dependencies,
        func: func
      });
    } else {
     func();
    }
    processWaiting();
  };
})();

new Service('D', ['this', 'one', 'will', 'fail'], function() {});

new Service('A', ['B', 'C'], function() {
 console.log('A is ready');
});

new Service('B', [], function() {
 console.log('B is ready');
});

new Service('C', [], function() {
 console.log('C is ready');
});
```